# How to combine/pool the standard error of fitting parameters from multiple fits of the same model?

Tags: time-series, standard-error, goodness-of-fit, curve-fitting, pooling

Let me first explain the context of the problem:

I have a time series of the (z-)positions of a particle relative to a surface. For 5 independent subsamples of this time series, I calculate the autocorrelation function (ACF) using the following python function:

```
def autocorr_meansubtr(x):
    x_meansubtr = x - x.mean()
    xnorm = np.sum(x_meansubtr**2)
    acor = np.correlate(x_meansubtr,x_meansubtr,'same')/xnorm
    return acor[round(acor.size/2):]
```

I then fit each ACF curve using the lmfit package for Python, specifically using its [built-in exponential model](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#exponentialmodel) $ f(x; A,\tau) = A\exp{(\frac{-x}{\tau})}$ , which gives a standard error for each fitted parameter as - to my limited understanding - is estimated by ["inverting the Hessian matrix which represents the second derivative of fit quality for each variable parameter. The standard errors or 1σ uncertainties are those that increase chi-square by 1."](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html)

I want to find the best estimate for the decay time $\tau$ by pooling the results for several fits. I now use the mean of the 5 fitted $\tau$ values and use the standard deviation for these 5 values.

However, I do not think this is correct as (a) each $\tau$ has a standard error associated with it which I don't take into account, and (b) I don't know the underlying distribution of the goodness of fits. I perhaps could find this with more than 5 fits, but I cannot obtain data for more fits within a reasonable timespan.

So my questions are:

(1) How would I go about combining the standard errors of the fits?

(2) I found methods which I think apply to (1), but they require knowing the amount of samples per fit; what is the analog of the amount of samples for fitted parameters? The number of fit attempts?

(3) Is the mean a of these fits a proper way to represent the best estimate of the decay time? I.e. for some fits 4/5 seem to closely align with the data, whilst one fit is rather off; would the median be a better estimate? I suppose in case the data does in fact deviate from the rest of the data and the difference is not caused by problematic fitting this introduces bias..

Sidenote: as one with any statistical prowess can probably infer; my statistics class was a while ago so I feel lacking of basic knowledge. Time constraints prohibit me (for now) from properly revisiting the subject. I'm not unwilling to put in the effort, but I have many other tasks waiting as well.

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!